# How to close 1 dialog box after another appears in flutter?

Tags: flutter

https://i.stack.imgur.com/czLib.jpg

In the above video I am redeeeming the  offer and then I am getting a confirmation dialog box that its successful. After 2 seconds the confirmation DB pops and then screen is refreshed. But I want the initial DB to pop as well after Confir. DB disappears. I am not able to do this. This is the code snippet:

```
showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              _timer = Timer(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              });
                              return AlertDialog(
                                content: Text(redemeResponseBody),
                              );
                            }).then((value) {
                          if (_timer.isActive) {
                            _timer.cancel();
                          }

                          Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2), () {
                            setState(() {
                              didRedeem = true;
                            });
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();

                            Get.to(() => OffersScreenPage(getIndex: 1));
                          });
                        });
```

Any idea? what's wrong

Comment: When you open the second dialog box, dismiss the first dialog box.

Comment: Here we know that there will be 2 dialog box , so just write 2 times Navigator.of(context).pop(); one after another, After successful redeem.

Comment: Yes thankyou this worked. Just had to write another pop after the first one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest reading the [Navigator API documentation.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html). The `popUntil()` method seems to be what you're after.